# Flexbox container items aligned to the left

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create a grid using Flexbox.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item one"></div>

  <div class="item two"></div>

  <div class="item three"></div>

  <div class="item four"></div>

  <div class="item five"></div>

  <div class="item six"></div>

  <div class="item seven"></div>
</div>
```

The things I want is to make the last div aligned to the left (without using `float`), see the example below.

[JS Bin example](https://jsbin.com/sohesowefo/1/edit?output)

Just for better visualization I attach the image - pay attention to **the last two product cards** which are aligned to the left [image]

So, how can Flexbox help solve such problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex-direction:column` and `align-self:flex-start`

#### SNIPPET

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 325px;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
.item div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
}
/*.sale {
  align-self: flex-start;
}*/

div div div:nth-of-type(3) {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item one">
    <div>ITEM</div>
    <div>DESC</div>
    <div class='sale'>SALE</div>
    <div>PRICE</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item one">
    <div>ITEM</div>
    <div>DESC</div>
    <div class='sale'>SALE</div>
    <div>PRICE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item one">
    <div>ITEM</div>
    <div>DESC</div>
    <div class='sale'>SALE</div>
    <div>PRICE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item one">
    <div>ITEM</div>
    <div>DESCRIPTION</div>
    <div class='sale'>SALE</div>
    <div>PRICE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item one">
    <div>ITEM</div>
    <div>DESC</div>
    <div class='sale'>SALE</div>
    <div>PRICE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item one">
    <div>ITEM</div>
    <div>DESC</div>
    <div class='sale'>SALE</div>
    <div>PRICE</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item one">
    <div>ITEM</div>
    <div>DESC</div>
    <div class='sale'>SALE</div>
    <div>PRICE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx, but it's not what I am looking for, because you need to style the last divs manually every time. I just want them to be aligned by default, say like Bootstrap container-fluid does. If the viewport is too small to contain all items, it just puts the rest of items to the next line starting from the left.

Comment: How else would you single out the ones you want to offset? Bootstrap you'd have to do the same thing. There are ways to use nth selectors, which is harder to maintain but you wouldn't need to put a class on single elements. See update.

Comment: Yeah, it is useful for sure - thank you, but perhaps there's another way to go. Though I'm not sure yet